# Convert list of list of dicts to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have large json data that is read into a python dataframe, and creates a list of dicts per row. I need to convert it into a different format of data.

The data format is the following:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "item": [{
                    "value": 0,
                    "type": "a"
                },
                {
                    "value": 0,
                    "type": "b"
                },
                {
                    "value": 70,
                    "type": "c"
                }
            ],
            "timestamp": "2019-01-12T04:52:06.669Z"
        },
        {
            "item": [{
                    "value": 30,
                    "type": "a"
                },
                {
                    "value": 0,
                    "type": "b"
                }
            ],
            "timestamp": "2019-01-12T04:53:06.669z"
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be the most efficient way of converting the data to a dataframe of the form:

timestamp-----------------------------a-------b------c

2019-01-12T04:52:06.669Z------0-------0------70
2019-01-12T04:53:06.669Z------30------0------0

So far I have managed to do it using for loops, but its very inefficient and slow. What I have so far is this.

```
with open('try.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df_data = pandas.DataFrame(data['data'])
df_formatted = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])

for d, timestamp in zip(df_data['item'], df_data['timestamp']):
    row = dict()
    for entry in d:
        category = entry['type']
        value = entry['value']
        row[category] = value
    row['timestamp'] = timestamp
    df_formatted = df_formatted.append(row, ignore_index=True)
df = df_formatted.fillna(0)
```

The number of items in the list is often in several thousands.Any pointers or examples about how to do this efficienty?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack the nested json object by iterating over the objects. Try

```
import pandas as pd
a=[
      {
       "item": [
          {
            "value": 0,
            "type": "a"
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "type": "b"
          },
          {
            "value": 70,
            "type": "c"
          },
        ],
        "timestamp": "2019-01-12T04:52:06.669Z"
     },
     {
        "item": [
          {
            "value": 30,
            "type": "a"
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "type": "b"
          }
        ],
        "timestamp": "2019-01-12T04:53:06.669z"
      }
]


cols = ['value', 'type', 'timestamp']

rows = []
for data in a:
    data_row = data['item']
    timestamp = data['timestamp']
    for row in data_row:
        row['timestamp']=timestamp
        rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df =df.pivot_table(index='timestamp',columns=['type'],values=['value']).reset_index()
df.columns=['timestamp','a','b','c']
```

If you are looking for a compact solution use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html#pandas-io-json-json-normalize)

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df =pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(a)):
    df =pd.concat([df,json_normalize(a[i]['item'])])
df =df.pivot_table(index='timestamp',columns=['type'],values=['value']).reset_index()
df.columns=['timestamp','a','b','c']
```

Final output

```
timestamp                   a       b       c
2019-01-12T04:52:06.669Z    0.0     0.0     70.0
2019-01-12T04:53:06.669z    30.0    0.0     NaN
```

Comment: What I want is the 'type' to become column header, and the value as rows. Sorry if it was not clear from the question

Comment: @user367231 You can pivot it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a list of dictionaries from the json and feed it into a dataframe. Code could be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict([('timestamp', d['timestamp']), ('a', 0),
                         ('b', 0), ('c', 0)]
                        + [(item['type'], item['value'])
                           for item in d['item']])for d in data['data']],
                  columns=['timestamp', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

print(df)
```

outputs as expected:

```
                  timestamp   a  b   c
0  2019-01-12T04:52:06.669Z   0  0  70
1  2019-01-12T04:53:06.669z  30  0   0
```

The trick here is to first build a list of pairs with default values and then extend it with the actual values before building a dict from it. As the last seen values is kept, you actually build a dictionnary containing all relevant values.

The columns parameter is only present to ensure the expected order of columns.